# How should I repair my Fiberglass Tub?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, epoxy

I assume my tub is fiberglass because it flexes a bit when I stand in it.

There is rust around the drain, so I'm not 100% sure about the fiberglass-ness of the tub. But, I'm a n00b in general.

[Photos of Tub Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXzzZ.jpg)
----------

I'd like to refresh the tub and not replace it. I've seen epoxy kits from Rust-o-leum for example and am wondering if that is a good option.

There are two issues I'd like to address.

1. The rust around the drain.
2. The low spot where the water ring is (near the drain)

My plan of attack is this:

- sand down the rust until its clear of rust.
- use an epoxy repair product to fill in the rust ring and raise up the low area.
- sand down the epoxy to make smooth/level
- scuff up the entire tub and use an epoxy coating product to renew the surface

Am I missing anything? Any pitfalls to look out for? Experiences with these epoxy repair and resurfacing products?

[image: Low spot and rust ring]

[image: Rust ring closeup]

Comment: It's likely a thin steel tub which was not properly bedded (*i.e.* set into a bed of plaster) at installation. Having had one exactly like that, I'm afraid the only real solution is a new tub, but you can waste your time with paint for a while until you work up to that if you like. You'll get there eventually. Try a magnet if you still think it's fiberglass - a magnet will stick to a steel tub, but not to a fiberglass (or other plastic) one.

Comment: I agree with Ecnerwal that tub needs bedding added prior to throwing any money down that drain quite literally. If the bottom flexes the repair will not last, rebedding and adjusting the tub so it drains are first then consider refinishing. The flexing has caused the coating to chip.